# Filter autorun programs on usb

Tags: windows-7, usb, autorun

I set my windows to start with my application instead of Explorer, and I disabled modifier Keys like Ctrl-Alt.., etc. so that the user can't use the PC outside of my startup application.

I want to make a maintenance Autorun app on a USB drive that activates the modifier keys. The problem is that anyone could do the same, so how do I allow only my app to Autorun from the USB drive?

I know that I could disable Autorun and use my app to start the maintenance program, but it would be preferable not to rely on my startup app in case it stopped working.

Comment: This is not a Question and Answer forum, What has your research effort shown using Google? Questions on SU are expected to show some research effort on your part and should be included in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autorun only has two states; on or off, so it's an all-or-nothing deal.  Your only configuration options are what drives to enable or disable it on, but you can't whitelist specific applications that Autorun can launch.  However, since Autorun is a feature of Explorer, not Windows, it shouldn't apply to you because you are not using Explorer as your shell.

That being said, there are features of Windows 7 that can whitelist/blacklist specific applications from running.  There are Software Restriction Policies and AppLocker, which are typically used in corporate domains, but are accessible from the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`) of non-domain computers.  The only requirement is that you are running Win7 Enterprise, or Ultimate (for AppLocker).  It won't work on the Home and Pro editions (Software Restriction Policies may work on Pro).

You can access the setting by hitting Start -> Run, `gpedit.msc`.  Then go to Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Software Restriction Policies or Application Control Policies.

I would recommend reading Microsoft's documentation before using them, because they can make life miserable if not done correctly.  But it is possible to craft a policy that allows you to whitelist *only* specific applications from a USB flash drive.

Comment: Upon further investigation, AppLocker will **NOT** run on Win7 Pro.  Only the Enterprise and Ultimate editions are supported.  I'm not sure about Software Restriction Policies, however, since those have been around since Windows XP/Server 2003.  I edited my answer to reflect this.